# .htaccess keeps redirecting to 401

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I've been trying to get this to work for an hour.

I'm protecting a directory with .htaccess and .htpasswd

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "Access Denied: Please Enter the Correct Information to Continue"  
AuthUserFile /actual/path/based/on/php/info/.htpasswd  
require valid-user
```

Simple stuff. For some reason I'm getting a 401.shtml page instead of asking for login information.

- I've tried disabling the other redirects
- I'm pretty sure the path is correct
- This works just fine on another site, just different web hosts.

Thanks.

Comment: **Have you got any other `.htaccess` files in parent directories which define an `ErrorDocument` for 401s?** I've got the same trouble in that case. The errdoc is delivered instead of the login dialog. Disabling the errdoc definition for 401s allows login as expected, but a canceled login will result in a default generated 401 page, instead of your custom page. I'm still looking for a solution to that bit.

Comment: It's been over a year since I faced this issue - it turned out the host was running an outdated version of PHP and (IIRC), an issue with `magicquotes`. These days I use a custom user system - when I canceled a log in attempt using this method it forever directed to 'Unauthorized'. Sorry I couldn't be more help.